# R cant loop concatenate directory and file name

Tags: r, loops, vector, concatenation

I am trying to loop paste a directory folder path and some csv file names from this folder below, but getting error. Please help!

```
#

# Create String of Directory fpath

strdir <- getwd()

vec_files <- dir(path = getwd(), pattern = "*.csv") 

# Loop

for (i in 1:length(vec_files)) {

  print0(strdir,"/",vec_files[[i]], sep = "")

}
```

Returns error below:

> Error in print.default(strdir, "/", vec_files[[i]], sep = "") :
>   invalid printing digits -2147483648 In addition: Warning message: In
>   print.default(strdir, "/", vec_files[[i]], sep = "") :   NAs
>   introduced by coercion

Comment: You have a typo. Use paste0 instead of print0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @teofil you probably want to use `paste0` instead of `print0` as there is no function named `print0`. Moreover, even after using `paste0` the loop will not print anything since in `for` loop you need to print the objects explicitly so wrap another `print` or `cat` around `paste0` for it to work.

However, you really don't need to do this. `dir()` and `list.files()` have `full.names` parameter which gives the full path of the files if set to `TRUE`.

```
vec_files <- dir(path = getwd(), pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
```

Also note that if you are reading from your working directory itself you don't necessarily need the complete path of the file, although it is a good habit to work with complete path always.